# Send multiple <option>s through form

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Available Areas</legend>
    <select id="availableAreas">
        <?php  
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM workArea";
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $area = $row['name'];
            echo "<option value='$id'>$area</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input id="addArea" type="button" value="Add area" /><br />
    <select id="workAreas" style="min-width: 200px" required multiple name="workAreaId"></select>
</fieldset>
```

The code above produces this output:

[image]

I haven't put the JavaScript in as it's not relevant to the question but clicking 'Add area' would add the area into the `<select>` element (the multiple list below the drop down).

When the user submits the form I need to send all of the `<option>`s that the user added to the list. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, can't you just fill out a disabled text-area with the data you need?

Comment: @DainisAbols I don't think HTML sends disabled form data. Might be wrong but otherwise this is a good suggestion.

Comment: If you have a multiple `select` element then all the selected elements will be submitted to the server but items should be selected.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes I could do that but I don't want the user to have to select every option after adding them if you know what I mean.. they should just automatically send.

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment, I just now saw that you already have a multiple select in your code. Now that I saw that ... what's your actual problem? When you submit the form the multiple select field will be sent ... I don't see what you need more.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider By default the only options that will be sent are the ones that are selected. I don't want the user to have to select them manually after clicking the 'Add area' button.

Comment: You can always use `CTRL + Click` to select multiple choices too.

Comment: @DainisAbols That is true but still doesn't meet client requirements. I think what I'll do is generate a custom style text input for every added area. It's either that or use JavaScript to manually select everything in the list when the full form is submitted (full form can't be seen in image/code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery:

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function() {
    $('#workAreas option').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

This should select all items in your multiple select when the form is submitted.

Another option would be to add a hidden input field for every Option. When you add `[]` to the name of the field it will be available on the server side as an array.

```
<input type="hidden" name="workareas[]" value="X" />
```